# How do I prebuild a devcontainer including postCreateCommand settings in devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I found a couple other questions around here like this, with no answers.

I am using this project to prebuild a devcontainer and push it to Github Container Registry: https://github.com/devcontainers/ci/blob/main/docs/github-action.md

The relevant Github action step looks like this:

```
  - name: Build and run Dev Container task
    uses: devcontainers/ci@v0.3
    with:
      imageName: "ghcr.io/${{ env.OWNER_LC }}/dev-infra-environment"
      cacheFrom: "ghcr.io/${{ env.OWNER_LC }}/dev-infra-environment"
      push: filter
      refFilterForPush: refs/heads/main
```

After reviewing the logs, the `postCreateCommand` defined in the `devcontainer.json` is not executed. And when I pull the image in vscode to use as a devcontainer, it runs the `postCreateCommand` then.

Is there a way to get the `postCreateCommand` (or some other mechanism) to run when the devcontainer is being built, so that everything is included in the final image? Documentation is really sparse on this, or any other mechanism for prebuilding devcontainers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container) the postCreateCommand is executed when container is created, it's not feasible for pre-builds. If you want to pre-build, there are many different options available. I'd consider using features (if available) or building from a Dockerfile with all required packages.